# Mentioning users via slack in webhooks

Tags: python, bots, slack

I'm building somewhat integration github with slack, which will notify users (reviewers of pull request) and send them link in #general chat.

And I'm struggling with mentioning users, right now I found only one way to mention them: via `username` in Slack, however to know this `username`, I must ask person to give it to me. Mentioning via `<@display_name>` doesn't seem to work, even with `link_names: 1` parameter.

Comment: Not sure what your issue might be, but I can confirm mentions work when adding the `link_names: 1` (@username was used in the text of the message)

Answer (score 36):

You can mention users through `<@memberID>` as text in the Slack webhook. This will post a username as a string.

For example, if there is a user named John with `memberID` `UC6B12Z4N`, then pass `<@UC6B12Z4N>` in the Slack webhook. This will mention `@John` with the correct link.

[How to find my Member ID in Slack workspace?](https://medium.com/@moshfeu/how-to-find-my-member-id-in-slack-workspace-d4bba942e38c)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the email you can also use the syntax mentioned by @Achyut but just with the "email" part. At least for me that helps a lot as finding the user/memberId is somewhat annoying.

Email -> someuser@company.com

To the bot:

```
{
 "text": "Hello <@someuser>"
}
```

This works even if the user has another "alias" in their name.

Cheers!

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: how are you using it?, I have a working bot which tags users this way and it works like a charm